# Tensorflow: What's the difference between tf.nn.dropout and tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper?

Tags: tensorflow

How's the following codes different?

- with tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper

  ```
  enc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_sizes, output_keep_prob=1-keep_prob) for _ in range(num_layers)])

  _, encoding_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(enc_cell, rnn_inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
  ```
- with tf.nn.droupout

  ```
  enc_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(rnn_size) for _ in range(num_layers)])

  _, encoding_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(enc_cell, tf.nn.dropout(rnn_inputs, 1 - keep_prob), dtype=tf.float32)
  ```

It seems that there is a difference in the number of states we get from tf.nn.dynamic_rnn. len(encoding state) is greater with tf.nn.dropout.

An explanation will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind both is the same and it is dropout: the network "drops" (i.e does not use) some of its nodes in the prediction. This means reducing during training the capacity of the model to prevent overfitting. Thanks to dropout, the network learns not to rely exclusively on particular nodes for its prediction.

The difference between the two methods is that:

- `tf.nn.droput`is a generic function to perform droput to a given input tensor. Looking at the documentation:

  > Computes dropout.
  >
  > With probability `keep_prob`, outputs the input element scaled up by 1 /
  >   `keep_prob`, otherwise outputs 0. The scaling is so that the expected
  >   sum is unchanged.
- `tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper` or `tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper` is a specific class to define Recurrent Neural Network cells with dropout applied both at the input and the output of the cell. Looking at the documentation:

  > Operator adding dropout to inputs and outputs of the given cell.

  In particular, it [uses](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L770) `tf.nn.droput` to mask the input to the cell, the state and the output.

The difference between your two pieces of code is that when you are using `tf.nn.dropout` you are masking the inputs of the first layer only. In the wrapper case, layer per layer, you are masking the outputs of the cells (since you are providing only the output probabilities )

Comment: Do you know why the number of states we get from the second code is greater than the first piece of code?

Comment: I can't figure out why. For me in both cases, you should have a number of states equal to the number of layers. This is how the MultiCell should work as far as I know. The only thing I can notice is a missing parenthesis after rnn_sizes in the first piece of code.

Comment: Yes, I also can't understand why the number of states is different. The missing parenthesis is a typo which probably happened when I pasted the code in the browser. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think dropout can only mask one end, like what you did with rnn_inputs.
DropoutWrapper can mask multi end, like a lstm cell.